# ShareActionProvider with a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment, shareactionprovider

I would like to use a `ShareActionProvider` to share the contents of my `ListFragment` (which consists of text entries from an `ArrayAdapter` fed with a `ArrayList<MyObject>`).

How do I do this?

I know that I will have to create a new Intent and to use `setType("text/plain")` but for `setAction()` should I use `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`?

When setting the content, should I use `putExtra` or `putParcelableArrayListExtra`?

Do I set the Intent with the data from the `ListFragment`, or from the `ArrayAdapter`, or from the `ArrayList<MyObject>` that is fed into `ArrayAdapter`, or from the data before the `ArrayList` were constructed?

Answer (score 0):

> for setAction() should I use Intent.ACTION_SEND and Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE?

That is your choice to make, as the author of the app. If you are expecting to share *one* piece of text (that you assembled from many pieces yourself), use `ACTION_SEND`. If you are expecting to share *many* pieces of text, use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Note that I would expect about a 100:1 ratio of apps supporting `ACTION_SEND` compared to `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. So, if your objective is for this sharing to be generally useful, you would want to steer towards `ACTION_SEND`.

More importantly, you need to determine what the *users* are going to want to do. Presumably, the point behind your development is for 1+ humans to use this app. If the user of the app is expecting to send *one* email, or post *one* tweet, or upload *one* note based on this data, you should be using `ACTION_SEND`. If, instead, the user will be expecting to send *N* messages (or whatever), then that would be something to try with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

> When setting the content, should I use putExtra or putParcelableArrayListExtra?

For `ACTION_SEND`, it would be `putExtra()`, passing in the `String`. For `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, it would be `putStringArrayListExtra()`.

> Do I set the Intent with the data from the ListFragment, or from the ArrayAdapter, or from the ArrayList that is fed into ArrayAdapter, or from the data before the ArrayList were constructed?

You use a `String` or `ArrayList<String>` as noted above. Where you get those values from is *your business logic* that *you as a developer* need to decide.

Comment: But my `ArrayAdapter` gets populated by an `ArrayList<MyObject>`, not an ArrayList<String>`. Even so, I can't use `ArrayList` on a `ACTION_SEND`? Am I supposed to loop through the ArrayList with a for loop and build a `StringBuilder` that I feed to `putExtra`?

Comment: The `ListFragment` is a list that contains *multiple* text entries. I want to send the whole list (consisting of *multiple* text entries). Should I use `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`?

Comment: @Fred: You claim that you are trying to send `text/plain`. *You* need to assemble the `String`(s) to send, because *you* are the only one who knows what those `String`(s) are supposed to look like. "Should I use ACTION_SEND or ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE?" -- please re-read the first three paragraphs of my answer. Your MIME type is `text/plain`. Whether you are sending one `String` or N `Strings` is dependent upon your business rules.